# Горизонтальная линия справа от текста до конца элемента

Tags: html

Есть таблица:

```
<table>
<tr><td>АРБУЗ ---------</td><td>СЕМЕЧКИ</td></tr>
<tr><td>БОЛЬШОЙ АРБУЗ -</td><td>СЕМЕЧКИ</td></tr>
</table>
```

Как сделать линию в зависимости от длины содержимого?
Или на таблицах такое не получится сделать?

Comment: @oscar2000, можно скриптом сделать, но, собственно, зачем это нужно-то? Может, можно как-то по-другому, попроще?

Comment: Спасибо ребят. Не, скриптов и так как опой жуй :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/w3thfu33/)

```
td:first-child {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
td:first-child:after {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

То, что это таблица вовсе не проблема. В ячейку таблицы всегда можно поместить див и растяуть его по ячейки. Тут ключевой вопрос в том, однородный ли у вас фон под текстом? Если да, сделайте линию фоном, а "Большой арбуз" оберните в инлайн блок и залепите ему тот же самый фон, что и под таблицей. Если нет, то в ячейке вам нужно сделать двухколоночный макет, где левая колонка берет ширину "по содержимому", а правая все оставшееся. Ну и в правую, соответствено, фон. Обращайте внимание на возможные переносы строк. Возможно, их надо запилить white-space: nowrap;